# Get text of About link, on Google.com using CSS selector : Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I am new to Selenium Webdriver. 
This might seem naive, but as a part of my learning I am trying to get the text of "About" link on google.com. I wanna do this only using cssSelector.hyperlink
So far I have tried multiple variations of the following:

WebElement we= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#fbar>a[href='/intl/en/about.html']"));

Somehow every time, I hit an error, of not able to locate the element.

Can anyone solve this and help me explain how can we achieve this using cssSelector?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium but it would most likely be a great help if you include the error you're running into.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues with your CSS:

1. You didn't put a space between `#fbar>a`, so it's looking for an `a` element that is directly a child of an element with `id="fbar"`
2. The `href` has more text than what you're trying to match

This CSS selector should work for you:

```
#fbar a[href^='/intl/en/about.html']
```

This fixes 1. by telling the selector to look for an `a` element that is a child of an element with `id="fbar"` (and not necessarily a direct descendant) and 2. looking for a match for `href` which starts with the text you're looking for.

This is a solid reference for CSS selectors:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks ! That did the trick. But, the "#fbar> a" still throws an error ,unable to locate element, with the space and the extra text, I tried this " #fbar > a[href^='/intl/en/about.html']